# Add a custom function to widget code

Tags: functions, widgets

Hopefully, this is an easy question - I'm just a bit confused.

I've got a custom widget with the usual structure:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
  function My_Widget() {
    // widget actual processes
  }
  function form($instance) {
    // outputs the options form on admin
  }
  function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    // processes widget options to be saved
  }
  function widget($args, $instance) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
  }
}
register_widget('My_Widget');
```

I's like to add my own custom function to it, so I can reuse it. Something like:

```
function item_width_cols_to_class( $cols_num = null ) {
    if( $cols_num ){
        switch ( $cols_num ){
            case '2':
                return "col140";
                break;
            case '3':
                return "col220";
                break;      
            case '4':
                return "col300";
                break;      
            case '5':
                return "col380";
                break;
            case '6':
                return "col480";
                break;      
            case '7':
                return "col540";
                break;      
            default:
                return "";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I add that code to My_Widget class I got an error saying: `"Fatal error: Call to undefined function 'item_width_cols_to_class()'"`. I'd think it's possible to add custom functions to a widget as it extends the WP_widget class.

Am I doing something wrong? :S

Thanks for help, Dasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you call your `item_width_cols_to_class` "function"?

You are using the function as a method inside the `My_Widget` class. Therefore, you have to call it with a reference to its non-existent object e.g. `$this->item_width_cols_to_class()` or `self::item_width_cols_to_class()` (static).

Comment: yep that's exactly it! I defined the function and am calling it from within `My_widget` class. I ended up using `$this->item_width_cols_to_class()`. Still a bit confused with `$this` (will keep on learning). Thanks a lot for super fast answer :)

Comment: @dashaluna: I'm trying to explain that for you (attetion: bad english skills incoming). You're going to create a new object of your `My_Widget` class somewhere in your code (WP will do that for you). Think of this snippet `$obj = new My_Widget();`. `$obj` has now a reference to this object. Everytime you want to access a class-member, you could call `$obj->yourMethod()`. This only works, because you've created an object with `new`. Inside your class, you want to do something without the need of creating a object of its own. There you can use the `$this` reference, which points to its own.